# can't drop image from jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I can't drop a image inside jquery dialog to a drop area...

the image can drag but can't drop on new position on drop area...

it moves back when dropped...

I modified codes from jquery website,

anybody can help me ....

I really don't know how to fix this bug ...

```
<HTML>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js"></script>   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easydrag.js"></script>   
        <style>
            #droppable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 0px;}
        </style>
        <script>
            var draggableArguments={
                scope: "items",
                cursor: 'hand',
                revert:'invalid',
                helper:'clone',
                appendTo: '#droppable',
                scroll: false,
                containment: 'DOM',
                zIndex: 1500,
                addClasses: false,
            }
            $(function() {
                $( "#dialog" ).dialog({title: 'Some title', width:300, eight:600});
                $("#drag").draggable(draggableArguments);
                $( "#droppable" ).droppable()
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="demo">
            <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
                <div id="drag">
                    <img src="low.gif"/>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
                <p>Drop here</p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- End demo -->
    </body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

I corrected your code:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>   
<script>
var draggableArguments={
    cursor: 'hand',
    appendTo: '#droppable',
    scroll: false,
    containment: 'DOM',
    zIndex: 1500,
    addClasses: false
}
$(function() {
    $("#drag").draggable(draggableArguments);
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( ui.draggable ).remove();
            $( ui.draggable.html() ).appendTo( this );
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
<div id="drag">
    <img src="low.gif"/>
</div>  
</div>
<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
    <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hye, 
You need to specify what will happen when you drop the element:
If you want to insert your draggable into the droppable, you need to write this action.

The source from the jquery-ui doc:

```
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
            $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
        }
```

When drop, they add an element in a list with the text of the draggable element.